# Joomla 3.10.3 - Не отображаются поля при создании\редактировании материалов и модулей

Tags: joomla

Не отображаются поля при создании\редактировании материалов и модулей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На месте красной полосы должно быть поле "Заголовок" как на фото ниже (выделено зеленым):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за того что полей кроме HTML редактора просто нет я не могу сохранить или создать Материал - появляется ошибка "Предупреждение Необходимо заполнить поле: Заголовок...."

[image: ошибка]

Есть какие-то настройки для отображения этих полей или куда копать в коде?

Answer (score 0):

Обновлял PHP на 8 - не встал, пол сайта не отображалось.
7.4 норм зашел.

Проблема решилась обновлением джумлы до версии 3.10.8